# Django 'migrate' command suggesting errors related to packages

Tags: python-3.x, django, anaconda, backend, migrate

I am new to Django and python and am presently taking a course on full stack web development, after following the course exactly the way it shows I have typed the following code within the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

And have tried to execute the command:

python manage.py migrate

The following is the error I get when calling  this command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Naseem\desktop\my_django_stuff\first_project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\Naseem\desktop\my_django_stuff\first_project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\Naseem\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Naseem\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
File "C:\Users\Naseem\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\Naseem\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Users\Naseem\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
File "C:\Users\Naseem\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

The following is the settings.py file, installed_apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]
```

And the admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

The course showed the models.py file working without adding anything to admin.py, I am not sure why it is showing these errors.

Comment: please provide your settings 'INSTALLED_APPS' list and 'admin.py'

Comment: I have just added the following files as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using foreign keys in your models, you have to set the on_delete parameter so django knows what to do with the entries when the model entry your foreign key is pointing to is deleted.

You could fix your models.py like this:

```
# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

You can read more about the different choices you have for this field [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) and what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your installed_app list write

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .........
    'first_app.apps.FirstAppConfig',
]
```

insted of just **'first_app'**
then in admin.py file add this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

myModels = [models.modelname, models.modelname.......]
admin.site.register(myModels)
```

then in your cmd first write

> python manage.py makemigrations

and then write

> python manage.py migrate

Hope this will work.